# Android: weird NullPointerException in ImageView widget

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Something a bit weird is happening in my code and I do not understand what is it...

I have some `Imageviews`, 4 of them, that can be clicked in order to launch the `CropActivity`, crop an image and the cropped image shall be displayed in the clicked `ImageView`.

So, **to find out which of the 4 `ImageViews` was clicked** I do like this:

```
public void onImageViewClicked(View v){
        String tag = v.getTag().toString();
        switch (tag){
            case "imgvW_1":
                this.clickedImgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvW_1);
                break;
            case "imgvW_2":
                this.clickedImgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvW_2);
                break;
            case "imgvW_3":
                this.clickedImgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvW_3);
                break;
            case "imgvW_4":
                this.clickedImgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvW_4);
                break;

        }

    }
```

So now...If I am correct....the clicked `ImageView` is stored in `clickedImgVw`.....

The problem is that...when I try to access `clickedImgVw` in `onActivityResult`, after the cropping, I get `NullPointerException`:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            ImageCropFunction();
        }
        else if (requestCode == 2) {
            if (data != null) {
                imgUri = data.getData();
                ImageCropFunction();
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (data != null) {

                CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

//THIS LINE HERE GIVES NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION ---------
                    String tag = clickedImgVw.getTag().toString();
//THIS LINE HERE GIVES NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION ---------

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(10))
                            .build();
                   imageLoader.displayImage(String.valueOf(resultUri),clickedImgVw, options);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What is it going on here?, What is wrong here?

*** ------- EDIT --------- ***

After some debug, I have noticed that the variable named `tag` changes its value on run time.

I have some screencaps showing it during the same debug run....when the application enters in a class named `AppCompatViewInflater.java` the variable `tab` loses its value

**Before `tag` gets a value:**

[image]

**After `tag` gets a value:**

[image]

**After entering `AppCompatViewInflater.java`:**

[image]

Comment: Throw an exception in switch default path, if the tag is something you do not expect. In this case you actually can get a NPE

Comment: show how you set tags to the views. Also why don't you just do `this.clickedImgVw = (ImageView)v;`?

Comment: hey Jens, thanks but I am very sure about the tags, I have put them in the XML code but also I have tested Logging the received `tag`, and it is always one of the 4 tags

Comment: @VladMatvienko I am actually not clicking the current ImageView, but the small icon overlaying the ImageView, this Icon gives me the tag referencing its ImageView

Comment: then you either have null `clickedImgVw` or your `clickedImgVw` has null tag, and `clickedImgVw.getTag()` is null. I don't know why because you don't show how you set tags. Also try using debug to check what is null.

Comment: @eddie: start the debugger :)

Comment: @VladMatvienko, thanks, yeah I will try, the tags are set via XML so I am quite sure about them

Comment: same sure as in your code? Better show it, cause I'm not sure.

Comment: @eddie set a breakpoint (or log.d) after the switch statement and see the value of clickedImgVw

Comment: @WilliMentzel yep I am working on it, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

**Activity.class**

```
public void onImageViewClicked(View v){
    String tag = v.getTag().toString();
    v.setTag("imgvW_1");
    switch (tag){
        case "imgvW_1":
            this.clickedImgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvW_1);
            this.clickedImgVw.setTag("imgvW_1");
            break;
        case "imgvW_2":
            this.clickedImgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvW_2);
            this.clickedImgVw.setTag("imgvW_2");
            break;
        case "imgvW_3":
            this.clickedImgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvW_3);
            this.clickedImgVw.setTag("imgvW_3");
            break;
        case "imgvW_4":
            this.clickedImgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvW_4);
            this.clickedImgVw.setTag("imgvW_4");
            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please add details of the problem and your solution to it

Comment: I think this code does not have a "setTag".  So I put the "setTag" code in the switch.